# How can I require authentication in Laravel 5 on a conditional basis?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I have an application which uses Laravel 5's out of the box authentication. I need to require authentication on the show method of a controller ONLY when the field called "approved" is equal to 1.

How can I require authentication using middlewares on a conditional basis such that unauthenticated users can access entries whose approved column is equal to 1, but only authenticated users can see entries where approved is equal to 0.

My constructor currently looks like this:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['edit', 'destroy', 'approve', 'markRecovered']]);
}
```

Comment: What table is this `approved` column present in? The `users` table or another table?

Comment: Another table for news entries, the controller is called NewsControlller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create your own middleware instead of using `Laravel`'s default `auth` middleware and in that case, you may create a middleware such as 'checkApproval' using something like this:

```
php artisan make:middleware checkApproval
```

Then in your `app/Http/Middleware` directory you'll find the new middleware created and it'll contain the basic structure including `handle` method, so now you may erite code inside this middleware's `handle` method to check the `user`'s state and the `approved` field and then either redirect to `login` page if condition doesn't match or allow access. here is a basic idea:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class CheckPermission implements Middleware {

    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($this->auth->guest() && !$this->checkApproval($request))
        {
            return redirect('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function checkApproval($request)
    {
        // Get the auth/logged in user
        // $user = $request->user();

        // Get a parameter from route
        // $id = $request->route()->parameter('id') 

        // Check the approved field here and return true or false
    }
}
```

Now assign the middleware a short-hand key in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file. By default, the `$routeMiddleware` property of this class contains entries for the middleware included with `Laravel`. To add your own, simply append it to this list and assign it a `key` to use in your `route/controller`, for example, `checkApproval` so in the place of `auth` you may use `checkApproval` for the the method `view` in your controller.

This is an abstract idea, but you can implement one of your own now so [check the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware) for more information.

Comment: This answer almost fixes my issue. Unfortunately, it's not the user that has the approved field, it is a news article. I only want the user to be able to see the news articles that are approved == 0 if they are logged in. Any thoughts on how to do such filtering?

Comment: Well, there is nothing so hard, only you need to chanhe the code according to your requirements in `handle` method. Just check the article's approved field and make the decission.

Comment: I understand from your examples how I should filter the data. I guess that where I'm struggling is in getting access to the current news article to check the field. I'll approve your answer regardless, but if you have any insight on getting access to the article, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just use the `ArticleInterface/ArticleRepository` (if you are using thos) or if you directky using a model in your controller then use that. For example, `use App\Repositories\Article\Article` and inject it in the `__construct` method like ` public function __construct(Guard $auth, Article $article)`, hope you got the idea. Also, you may use the `facade` or `app("App\Article")->get()`.

Comment: Doing so just gives me an empty article object, and not the current article object. What would be passing that additional parameter?

Comment: Actually, `app("App\Article")->get()` is just an example but that won't work, you need to `find` the article using the `id` from your route, you didn't provide any `URL` so can't be more specific, probably `app("App\Article")->find($id)` and make sure sure you get the `id` in `$id` variable from your `$request`, so you may use it like `$request->route()->parameter('id')`.

Comment: Thanks again. You were a great help.