# Upload, Store, and Download files with privacy restrictions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, security, laravel-5, file-upload

I'm developing a website where Administrator can upload files (in a restricted area just for administrators) and associate the files with users.
When regular users login to the website they'll have a "*Documents*" section where they can see the files that were uploaded and associated with them.

I dug a lot online but all the information made me confused so I thought of asking you all :)

**This is what I basically trying to achieve:**

1. An Administrator can access a restricted area where she can upload multiple files using an upload form and for each file, she can choose with which **users** to associate the file.
   *I Want to be able to create a form and before any update occurs, to list the file names and a Multi-Select box with all the users near each filename.*
2. The uploaded file will be associated with one or more users and users can be associated with more than one file. i.e *many-to-many* relationship.
   *I thought of creating a `file_user` pivot table so each File class can be associated with many instances of User class and vice versa.*
3. The name of the file should stay as the original name but there should be a possibility for duplicate names. Thus, I should create something to distinct the files and keep them unique (but still, with the same filename).
   *I thought of different folder names, but it will be messy in the server.*
4. Users should be able to access and download **only** files that are associated with them. They shouldn't be able to access a file which is not associated with them, neither to know of its existent. (i.e *File Not Found* instead of *Permission Denied*).

---

I already have an authentication implemented and I know how to create a page that is restricted only to Admin. In order to implement the files-upload and download services I thought of something like this:

1. Create a `File` model, with migration and Controller
2. Create a `FileController@create` (the multi-file upload form view), `FileController@store` (to store the files in the database), `FileController@index` (handles the view where the user sees the files associated with them and can download them) and `FileController@download` (responsible to download a file to an authorized user) functions in `FileController`.
3. Create views for the above methods
4. Create a `files` table in the database (via migration) to contain `file_id` and `file_name`.
5. Create a `file_user` pivot table because of their many-to-many characteristic.

I'm struggling with implementing the content of the above, with restricting the files to the allowed users, and I'm not sure that this is the best and most-secure approach.

How would you implement this?  If you have time, I'll appreciate if you'll add pieces of code for each stage so I can understand better. A simple application that implements this would be the best to learn from. So far I didn't find any online.

I would be happy to elaborate more and explain in details the pieces that weren't clear.
Thanks!

Comment: Achievement points 1 and 2 are clear. You got the right approach. Point 3 is a bit more tricky. I presume a user can't have 2 files with the same name but another user can have a filename that user 1 also has. For this I would create a unique filename that will be saved on the server. These unique filenames are linked to the user filename. In the same table. (filename, filename_token).

Comment: For numer 3, although there are many options, one of the simplest ways is to append time at the end of file name to make it unique, like `$fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extenstion`

Comment: yes of course, if a user downloads a file, you want the filename to be shown, not the token. This is simple ` <a href="/{filename_token}" download="{$filename}"> `

Comment: see https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp

Comment: For number 4, you can simply redirect to another page or 404 page if requested file is not associated with user id

Comment: no need @Ahsan. If the token is something like md5($user->id  . $filename . rand(100,1000)) there is no way any user will guess the filename. If Api Pota doesn't want users to share personal links to other users, that's another issue all together.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer all of what should have been separate questions. Instead of giving specifics on everything I will instead give a heads up on where it's common to have hick-ups.

For naming if files i insist that you let it be automatically generated. Be sure to add an extra fillable for your File Model containing the original name. Get the original file-name from the request with this line:

```
$fileName = time().'_'.$req->file->getClientOriginalName();
```

This name can then again be accessed on download and then be passed as an argument to the "Name" parameter when calling the download function.

The pivot table between user and file only needs a migration file in your database folder. When assigning an ID I strongly recommend using Uuid. It´s a breeze to add this to your models with Traits
https://www.larashout.com/using-uuids-in-laravel-models

**FilePage Migration**

```
Schema::create('file_pages', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('title')->nullable(true);
    $table->text('body')->nullable(true);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**File migration**

```
Schema::create('files', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    //$table->foreignId('file_page_id')->constrained();
    $table->uuid('file_page_id')->nullable(true);
    $table->foreign('file_page_id')->references('id')->on('file_pages')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string("name")->nullabe();
    $table->string("page_path")->nullabe();
    $table->string("view_name")->nullabe();
    $table->string("file_path")->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Remember to set `public $incrementing=false;` for the models using your Uuid trait

In your view you can serve your users the files both privately and publicly. Given that you configure your config/filesystems.php, run "php artisan storage:link" in your bash terminal and probs clear your storage cache too. Here is a really simple thing just to get you started:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{asset($file->file->file_path)}}" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<a href="{{asset($file->file->file_path)}}" type="audio/mp3"></a>
```

Audio plays the file. Anchor tag downloads it (with generated filename file-name).

For conditional behaviour of pages and ect I would read this thread:
[How can I require authentication in Laravel 5 on a conditional basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672303/how-can-i-require-authentication-in-laravel-5-on-a-conditional-basis)
Once you learn this, you can adapt your knowledge to make more auth middleware later on in your career